# Flattening an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, flatten

How can I flatten this array, that I've declared at the top of the class but not inside a method, into a single string inside a method?

```
private int[][]     numbers;
```

Comment: I am not aware there is a 'flatten' method in Java. You'd have to write that yourself.

Comment: Are you looking for the string representation of the multi-dimensional array? Or trying to flatten to a single array?

Comment: 'flatten an array of int arrays into a single String' just isn't a thing. You've imagined a term and a meaning. Which is fine, but nobody can answer this question unless you explain this in your question. For example, show an example int[][], and then show the string you'd like to turn it into.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int[] flattened = Arrays.stream(numbers).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
```

Or to flatten to a String:

```
String str = Arrays.stream(numbers)
  .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
  .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

This separates the numbers with a comma, but you can choose whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) method to convert a 2D array into a string:

```java
String str = Arrays.deepToString(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the 2d array and put them in a string, and this is how I did it :-)
Output:`325325`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][]  numbers =  {{3, 2, 5},
                        {3, 2, 5}};

    StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
            myString.append(numbers[i][j]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(myString);
}
```